# Can't get images working, with getResource()

Tags: java, image

I'm trying to make a jar, but the program needs images. When I ran the jar, the images didn't show up. However, they did in eclipse. I used this code:

```
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon("res/img/icon.png"));
```

Then I went looking on the internet for a way to fix it. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870517/exporting-images-with-jar-in-eclipse-java) question here on StackOverflow, but when i tried it in my code, it's throwing a `NullPointerException` (also in eclipse). This is my code now:

```
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/res/img/icon.png")));
```

The images are in a separate **folder** in the package, called "res":

[image]

Comment: make sure the image is actually inside of the Jar, and that it's inside the res/img/ directory.  Your syntax looks right

Comment: where your `res` is? It must be under your classpath

Comment: You should take a screenshot like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13695798/1834700

Comment: `NullPointerException` here means `.getResource()` returns `null`; and it does if the resource does not exist. Your image is not where you think it is...

Comment: @RongNK Does it actually have to look like that (my project setup)?

Comment: @CaspervanBattum Of course not. We just want to see your project layout, since your given resource URL is evidently incorrect.

Comment: @CaspervanBattum as a guess I'd say `res` is part of your project layout; try and remove `/res` in `.getResource()`

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding your project. In Eclipse, open the Navigator view. Open the /bin folder of the project. Does it have the /res/img/icon.png or instead /ing/icon.png ?

Comment: The path is correct, I'm 100% sure of that (checked it 10 times)

Comment: @Casper van Battum oh man, you have incorrect path, you should move `res` folder to `src` folder now !

Comment: Thanks, @RongNK. That actually worked (in eclipse atleast, for some reason it refuses to create a jar out of it...).

Comment: Good, it's working now both in, and out of eclipse! Thanks!

Comment: You didn't have to move res inside src. You just should say to Eclipse that res is a source folder, and thus would be included in the jar (project properties > Java Build Path > Source tab > Add Folder). And in the tree view you'll see the folder icon will change to a folder with a package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create a package inside your project, and name it something like "Images".
2. Now, add images you are using into this package.
3. Finally, call to these images, which are inside the package.

make sure you typed image names correctly as well

That is the best way of dealing with images

**update**

try

```
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("res/img/icon.png")));
```

instead of

```
label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/res/img/icon.png")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look that your `RES` folder is actually within the eclipse `SRC` folder.
Sometimes, users add a folder to the eclipse project instead.

Also:

- Try cleaning and rebuilding your project.
- In Eclipse, open the Navigator view. Open the /bin folder of the project. Does it have the `/res/img/icon.png` ( comment from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199439/getclass-getresource-always-returning-null) )